# angular - ng-model input is empty in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-model

I have this problem and I can't solve it.

When I get the values of input fields in my controller are all empty, why?

HTML

```
<input type="number" ng-model="formSearchAtt.numPartecipanti" id="partecipanti" value="0" class="price-input">

<button class="btn btn-default btn-green btn-3-column sidebar-filtri-button" ng-click="search()">Cerca</button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", function ($scope, $http, serviceRegioni, serviceRicercaAttivita, srvShareData) {

    $scope.search = function() {
    $scope.formSearchAtt = {'numPartecipanti' : ""};
    var numPartecipanti= $scope.formSearchAtt.numPartecipanti;
    console.log("numPartecipanti " + numPartecipanti);
}
});
```

Comment: So, you initialize a value (which should be a number, BTW) to an empty string, then immediately after, you print this value, and it's an empty string. What is surprising about that? If you want the value to be 0 by default, initialize it to 0. Its value will change when the user changes it (i.e. long after the initialization of the variable, when the user interacts with the UI)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", function ($scope, $http, serviceRegioni, serviceRicercaAttivita, srvShareData) {

   $scope.formSearchAtt = {'numPartecipanti' : ""};

   $scope.search = function() {      
        var numPartecipanti= $scope.formSearchAtt.numPartecipanti;
        console.log("numPartecipanti " + numPartecipanti);
    }
});
```

Declare your scope vars out of your "search" function.

When you will update the model of the input, $scope.formSearchAtt will be equal to what you entered in.